# Could free VPNs with public credentials be decrypted by ISP?

Tags: vpn

This is a question I could not answer by googling so far.
I was experimenting with Vpnbook VPN. The question may apply to any freevpn with public credentials.

Here goes: when I connect to one of their VPN servers, my ISP knows where I connect to, the free VPN server. Knowing that, they can easily identify that server as a vpnbook server, then go fetch the username and password credentials which are made public on the www.vpnbook.com web page. Then with this information, they should be able to decrypt my brownsing if they want to.

Is this true?
Ron

Answer (score 3):

The username and password are only used for authentication of the client against the server and have no function in the encryption process itself. They are only used to restrict who can use the service but not for protecting the data transfer. This means that everybody knowing these credentials can use the VPN service for themselves but not that they can decrypt the connections of others which use the same credentials. This is not only true for this VPN service but for example also for HTTPS connections.