# Can my university see the downloads from a Discord application when I use their Wi-Fi connectivity?

Tags: wifi, vpn

I didn’t use a VPN, and I am asking myself if my university can see the downloaded files or even the fact that I opened the [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord) application to download.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could free VPNs with public credentials be decrypted by ISP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/141898/could-free-vpns-with-public-credentials-be-decrypted-by-isp)

Comment: Did you have to install a certificate before you could access their network? If so: **YES**

Comment: If by "see that you are downloading something vs streaming vs generally navigating the web" the answer is that it is possible to detect, with very high confidence, if you are downloading, vs streaming, vs navigating the web because the patterns of data passing the wire, even when encrypted, are quite clear. So if the uni forbids "streaming online services on campus" they can be able to detect that even if you use a VPN.

Comment: @svin83 "Install a certificate" is imprecise; certificates are used not only for SSL interception, but also to authenticate servers in certain configurations (and one can 'install' them so that they work for only one purpose).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yeah. It **can** be done, but hardly anyone does that. Keeping tabs on, and logging public wifi traffic is the only way to stay 100% safe if the government suddenly shows up because wifi users have used your uplink for illegal activities... I work in the IKT Sector so I know...

Comment: The level of effort they want to put into it will matter.  Do you want to know if you are protected against *casual* knowledge, or against something on the level of a criminal investigation or government intelligence operatives?  Because at a certain level, TOR leaks enough connection information to reconstruct what you did, but not something that will show up in plain text school IT logs.

Answer (score 49):

Your university can see that you downloaded something from Discord. However, they probably can't see what exactly you downloaded.

More specifically, all of Discord's connections use TLS, so the data itself is encrypted. However, TLS still exposes the hostname via the [Server Name Indication extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Support_for_name-based_virtual_servers). So the university will see that your device communicated with `https://discord.com` and `https://cdn.discordapp.com`, but not what the contents of those communications were.

There are two uncommon edge cases:

- If you were using a university-owned device, all bets are off, and they potentially have full visibility into what that device was using.
- Some universities might require you to install a custom TLS root certificate to use their network. If you have a university-owned TLS root certificate installed, then they could decrypt TLS communications on their network and see what you downloaded. However, they can't set this up without your approval (either by installing the certificate yourself or by installing some security software that sets up the certificate for you).

Comment: [Some countries might require you to install a custom certificate as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakhstan_man-in-the-middle_attack)...

Comment: (1) SNI is not required if the destination IP address doesn't serve multiple domains (not shared host, not behind cloud NAT). (2) They can probably tell you *opened* Discord (it opens connections), though not what you did in there. (3) And on a more theoretical note, if the uni has a small list of possible files and very good logs, they might guess which one was downloaded by total transfer size.

Comment: Don't take my comment as criticism, though. Those are only minor additions, your answer is great.

Comment: @BoppreH I'm not 100% on this, but if chats use `discord.com` and media uses `cdn.discordapp.com`, then they can see you downloaded *something* just by dint of the different hosts. But well, all the memes also go via the CDN, so just opening certain channels with embeds on will constitute several downloads in this context.

Comment: @BoppreH Most large web services make use of third-party CDN services, so they're using shared IP addresses.

Comment: @BoppreH wouldn't SNI info be sent anyway even if the target server doesn't need it?

Comment: @ jaskij That's a good point, autoplaying media will be harder to catch. @ Barmar Another good point. But also keep in mind the context also reveals a lot, either because of preceding DNS requests or simultaneous requests to the API domain.
@ jcaron There's Encrypted SNI and more recently Encrypted Client Hello meant to hide this information. The CDN used by Discord [has supported ESNI for years now](https://blog.cloudflare.com/esni/), and I'd expect these initiatives to only grow larger.

Comment: @BoppreH Unless someone can show the Wireshark log of a Discord session, I'm not sure Discord actually uses ESNI. Plus ESNI has been discontinued in favor of ECH, which its adoption is still lacking anyway, most Cloudflare powered sites /cdn-cgi/trace still show they're using plain text SNI even though my browser already configured for ECH according to https://tls-ech.dev/

Comment: @Martheen I just ran a Wireshark scan with the Discord desktop app and the hostnames are still being sent in plaintext. https://imgur.com/a/a8suKe6

Comment: One thing I've never been clear on. The eduroam setup instructions i've seen include installing a certificate that will be used to verify the eduroam authentication server. If you don't install it you get security warnings on logging in to eduroam. What is not so clear to me is whether this certificate could in-principle also be used for MITM.

Comment: @PeterGreen That certificate is to identify the authentication server; when you connect to eduroam, your username/password are sent encrypted (TTLS or MSCHAPv2, Wi-Fi authentication), but there is no domain to verify, so in order to be sure that your client talks to the correct server, it needs to know which CA to trust, and which hostname to expect, in advance. Many eduroam providers install a CA that is already in the root store, but it must be provided explicitly due to how Wi-Fi is handled in the OS. Feel free to ask this as question, I’ll try to write a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: I went to ask the question, and it seems it was already asked. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/229645/eduroam-requires-installation-of-a-ca-certificate-can-they-decrypt-tls-traffic